# "Up to five tags" is often misinterpreted as "please enter five tags"

Tags: discussion, tags, new-users

[image: The tags field on a question says, add up to five tags to describe what your question is about.]

Asking for 'up to five tags' with a multi-lingual user base is resulting in new users entering extra tags because they think they **must** enter five tags, because the meaning of 'up to' may not apparent to users whose native language is not English.

This is I believe acting as an obstacle for users - they think:

> This is a C# question just about C#, but I have to find 5 tags? Um, ok, `visual-studio`, `.net`.. what else can I pick? Oh, I give up. I'll ask elsewhere."

The 5 tag limitation should in my opinion just be a validation error - *"You can only enter five tags per question"*.  I imagine a very small percentage of users would add more than five tags for a question, so I don't see this as being a usability issue. I also don't see tag spam as contributing to the overall quality of the site, or making a given question more likely to get a good answer.

Examples of questions where I think the poster is including tags just to make up the five:

[image: Question tagged with C#, Windows, Visual Studio, WinForms, and Windows Forms Designer.]

[image: Question tagged with C#, inheritance, polymorphism, automapper, and automapper 9.]

[image: Question tagged with c#, file, datetime, parsing, and read-write]

[image: Question tagged with c#, list, object, integer, and type-inference]

[image: Question tagged with c#, automated-tests, asp.net-core-mvc, dotnet-httpclient, and .net-3.0]

[image: Question tagged with c#, asp.net, linq, lambda, and entity-framework-core]

[image: Question tagged with c#, .net, arduino, serial-port, and usb]

[image: One question tagged with c#, .net-core, discord, discord.net, and netcoreapp3.0, and another question tagged with c# ,.net, apple-push-notifications, dotnet-httpclient, and http2]

[image: another example]

[image: another example]

[image: another example]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219436/discussion-on-question-by-stuartd-up-to-five-tags-is-often-misinterpreted-as).

Answer (score 8):

The tags like [arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrays) and [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string) are what are known as *dependent tags*. But they are **not** *meta tags* (which are [a specific subset of *dependent tags*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/)). They cannot be used alone, but they don't describe the *type* of the question  or the skill level of the author rather than the *content* of the question.

These tags are useful as a LEGO tag or a brick builder tag. It should not be removed because,

- **Complexity:** They eliminate the need for ultra specific tags: [java-arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-arrays) or [javascript-arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-arrays).
- **Classification:** They are easy to classify the question. A search for [arrays+javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrays+javascript) would yield all the questions you're looking for
- **Overlap**:  They allow questions about the concept where expertise in two languages are needed, which would not be possible without these LEGO tags

  - [How can I mimic Python's step argument in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62565087/how-can-i-mimic-pythons-step-argument-in-javascript)
  - [How to pass arrays from NodeJS to a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62989698/how-to-pass-arrays-from-nodejs-to-a-python-script)

Currently [arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrays) has around 30k watchers and [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string) has 4k watchers.

The How to tag tooltip also says

> How to tag
> Tags help the right people find and answer your question.
>
> > Include tags that are crucial to your question **only**, like c#

I believe that should be enough.

Comment: Note: [Question's original revision](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/400098/1) included arrays  specifically: *Realistically, we all here know tags like 'string' or 'array' or 'double' can't be followed by many people - why would they be, as 'array' could be C# or Rust or Lua arrays? (*) - and I see a lot of people including effectively extraneous tags just to make up the five*