# In an [ide]al world, there is no need for this tag

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Looking at the related tags list in [ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ide)'s [top-users page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ide/topusers) we can get a reasonable idea of how the tag is being used. **It mostly doubles with a second IDE specific tag**:

1. [eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse) - 1610 questions.
2. [intellij-idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intellij-idea) - 1003 questions.
3. [visual-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio) - 741 questions.
4. [netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netbeans) - 526 questions.

So looking at the [four burnination criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191):

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?** and **is it unambiguous?**

   Comparable to the [[script] tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/420832). Yes it's an IDE; but that's ambiguous because what you need to know is exactly **what IDE** is being talked about.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   Yes programming tools are on-topic; but it needs to be a specific programming tool otherwise the questions tend to be too broad or off-topic, for example:

   [Best C++ IDE or Editor for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89275/best-c-ide-or-editor-for-windows)

   [Best C++ IDE for *nix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79210/best-c-ide-for-nix)

   [Learning Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55574)

   [Angular2 - how to start and with which IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40840317)
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

   I don't see [ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ide) adding anything meaningful to a question that's already been tagged as [eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse) or [visual-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio) for example.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   Yes, but tagging a question as [ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ide) only adds redudancy and noise with no gain in discoverability nor meaning.

Comment: I think the tag might serve a purpose to illustrate that you are asking an IDE-related question given a certain tool chain. For example if asking about code formatting in Visual Studio and posting some code - you might want to make it clear that your question is about how to fix the formatting in the IDE, and not how to compile/link said code.

Comment: @Lundin tagging with `visual-studio` is enough in that scenario because the settings will be IDE specific.

Comment: @Lundin if an asker wants to make something clear (generally a good idea), they should describe it in the question and not make it clear by adding a tag.

Comment: @jps We use tags to describe what the question is about, in addition to the contents. They can do both.

Comment: I agree it's not the best tag, but there are over 10k questions using it. It is an on-topic tag, it is quite unambiguous and I don't really see how it is causing harm. We shouldn't start some massive busy-work undertaking just to remove a harmless tag.

Comment: I suppose the old "IDE" bus in PC computers might be an overlapping term.

Comment: @Lundin sure we do that. I can't edit my comment anymore, maybe I should have written "... and not just rely on a tag to make it clear". But still the specific tag, e.g. [visual-studio] would be sufficient IMHO.

Comment: @Lundin I took an in-depth look at the 10k Qs on the tag and only around 1% aren't **about** a *"specific ide"*. The remaining are off-topic, too broad, or very marginal *"ide agnostic"* questions that should get their own obscure marginal tag (as is usually the case with comparable burninations). Currently the tag is only used my novice users who don't understand the tag system, so it's a constant source of tag spam that needs to be edited out.

Comment: The search for [\[ide\] best](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bide%5Dbest) brings up a lot of opinion based/recommendation questions.

Comment: @jps that set of historically locked questions could maybe get their own tag as they're mostly https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ material. But something less obvious than just `ide` to avoid the tag being constantly added unnecessarily. Again, this post is open to retag suggestion of those historical cases.

Comment: The problem I can see with creating a *new* tag, @bad_coder, is we end up with a similar problem. People don't (can't) read, so they see a tag [[tag:windows]] and think that they can ask a question about how to change the start-up sound in Windows, or how to change the pane of glass in their bathroom *window*; they don't read the tag usage guidance that's shown to them when they add the tags as that required reading (which, again, too many users appear unable to be able to do). I can't envision a new tag, to replace [[tag:ide]], that doesn't get similar misuse.

Comment: If we had the ability to create a tag, and then *block* it's use on questions in the future (or limit it to moderators), that would be the ideal. If only there were an existing [[meta-tag:status-completed]] feature like that...

Comment: @ThomA [**retag guidance**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bstatus-completed%5D+%5Bburninate-request%5D+%22Retag+Guidance%22) is a common feature of burnination requests not barring blanket statements of *"users don't read tag guidance"* it's proven effective up to the point that a significant segment of users (including curators) does consider the tag usage. As for finding alternatives the `windows` behemoth tag makes for a poor comparison, so here's where the community's creativity is called for in finding workable alternatives.

Comment: I think you've missed the point of my comment there; my point is that I don't think there is a good alternative tag for IDE recommendations for historical questions.

Comment: The description for the tag currently states _"IDEs (Integrated Development Environment) are computer programs that facilitate efficient software development by providing features beyond those of a simple text editor."_. There is no usage guidance at all! Is there a case for appending some verbiage along the lines of _"Do not use this tag for new questions. It exists only for historical reasons."_? I fully understand that many don't read the usage guidance, but that is hardly a justification for not providing it.

Comment: @skomisa see [What is the purpose of the "DO NOT USE" tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271356). Deciding if that guidance should be added to the tag and how to proceed is part of this question.

Comment: @bad_coder Sure, _"Do not use..."_ is not necessarily the appropriate usage guidance for this tag; I proposed it as a suggestion. My larger point is that the tag currently contains no usage guidance at all, so we can hardly blame novice users for using it. I'm indifferent on the actual fate of the tag, but not about the quality (or absence) of its usage guidance.

Comment: I get that punny titles are good for burn requests, but this one is a bit of a stretch. I had to look twice to figure out which tag was being discussed.

Comment: @BhargavRao Are you back? Long time no see :)

Comment: @BhargavRao yeah, the tag blends so well into the idiomatic expression it seems natural. Best pun I've seen in a long time :D

Comment: I like the ide tag for the purpose of putting it on a tag ignore list. "I like Java questions but don't bother me with IDE questions". That's about it though.

Comment: @Gimby I'd say that's a separate concern, but a very real one. the guidance on not using meta tags is clear, but when I don't want to see anything about aws, I also don't want to have to manually add all the aws tags to my ignore list.

Comment: @TheMaster, just lurkin in the shadows.

Answer (score 12):

There might be some questions about IDEs that are IDE-agnostic similar to [Which @NotNull Java annotation should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4963300/10871900), [What is "Introspection-based code completion"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10905503/10871900) or maybe [difference between SDK and IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3196986/10871900) (these might not be good examples and the latter is closed but I think they are sufficient to get the point across).

In that case, [ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ide) would add meaningful information to the post and it's *not* useless without specific IDE tags.

If we come across questions like that, what about adding an [ide-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ide-agnostic) tag or similar?

For example, I could imagine people asking questions about general concepts like a variables view or similar.

Comment: I also recall a question I ran into recently-ish about what the word for "folding" was (as an example of a general feature terminology question).

Comment: Considering good names for narrower tags is key here! The incomplete [documentation burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361707) is one example where a good name (`documentation-generation`) for the remaining questions was devised. What to name and how to group those edge case question is the main question.

Comment: Your example question looks _too broad_ just from the title - it's an old generic dupe target, but the same question would not fly in 2024 and I struggle to think of any questions about IDEs which are IDE agnostic _and_ on topic for SO. If there are any such questions, they are probably about some specific thing in combination with IDEs and as such could just use the tags for the specific thing. So no, I think we do not need an ide-agnostic tag at all.

Comment: It is the first example I thought of. But things like "What is code folding?" (inspired by starball's comment) or other questions about generic IDE concepts would be on topic.

Comment: @dan1stiscrying "what is code folding" a) is about formatting or visual presentation and affects things which are definitely not IDEs (e.g. non-IDE editors, or diff viewers) and b) does not sound on-topic to me. "how do I implement this specific aspect of code folding" would clearly be on topic, but a generic "what does this word mean" or "explain this broad concept" question is IMO not - we're neither a dictionary nor an encyclopedia.

Comment: It does [look on-topic to me](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Asking for explaining a concept doesn't make something to broad IMO.

Comment: Why does a question about defining a debugger need the [tag:ide] tag? Why not just [tag:debugging]? The question you linked has survived just fine without an [tag:ide] tag for nearly 10 years.

Comment: @dan1stiscrying let's go down the list - it's not a specific programming problem, or
a software algorithm. It is somewhat related to software tools commonly used by programmers, but so are tons of other things that are off-topic (e.g. just because IDEs have themes does not mean discussing visual design is on-topic here). And "explain this concept" does not exactly sound like a _practical_ problem to me regardless of what specific concept it's about, so the last one is out as well. So no, it does not look on-topic to me according to the help page unless I squint very hard.

Comment: The linked example is just an example for the type of question. I was too lazy to look up a better example. I replaced it with an example that's maybe slightly better where the `[ide]` tag makes sense IMO.

Comment: @dan1stiscrying it would be a reductive mistake to think only in the usual terms of [ontology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology) because tags also require [pragmatism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmatism). Precisely, I made no argument beyond inviting readers to an empirical verification juxtaposing the [ide hypernym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyponymy_and_hypernymy) to its hyponyms. Not to persuade (much less to argue) but to verify the status quo of the IDE tag subset through its effective use as to draw any necessary conclusion from there.

Comment: @dan1stiscrying the hardest example to analyse you included is [Which @NotNull..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963300) It's actually **about** a problematic datatype that frequently causes problems with static type checkers and linters. Usually those tools are well integrated into IDEs (especially with compiled and statically typed languages) but if you check the Python ecosystem most of the linting/type checking is done by 3rd party tools external to the IDE. In short, it's one of the many Qs where an IDE specific Q will often be closed against the canonical dataype Q. `ide-agnostic`.

Answer (score 11):

I'm interested in the possibility and ok-ness of getting staff to just automate removal of the tag on any question that also has a tag for a specific IDE / editor. At the moment, I can't think of a reason why that wouldn't be a safe thing to do ("safe" as in- not messing up the meaning of the question post). Am I missing something?

One thing I'm not entirely sure about is questions that have multiple tags for different editors. I've seen some before, such as asking how to do something that one editor can do in a different editor, but I'm not sure if there are other types of questions with multiple different-editor tags where removing an [ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ide) tag might be a less desirable thing to do in terms of retaining the meaning of the question.

---

Also, have [a SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1815023):

```sql
SELECT
  PT_Other.TagId AS TagId,
  MAX(T_Other.TagName) AS TagName,
  COUNT(*) AS TagCount
FROM PostTags PT_IDE
JOIN PostTags PT_Other ON PT_Other.PostId = PT_IDE.PostId
JOIN Tags T_Other ON T_Other.Id = PT_Other.TagId
WHERE
  PT_IDE.TagId = 110 -- ide
  AND T_Other.Id <> 110
GROUP BY PT_Other.TagId
ORDER BY TagCount DESC
```

The total count of [ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ide) questions with editor tags as specified by [bad_coder's list](/a/427773/11107541) is 6946 ([see query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1815065)). The total count of [ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ide) questions is 10942 ([see query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1815068)) (since last SEDE refresh).

Comment: That's a good approach but interfacing with staff is usually done by a mod taking on the burninations so we'll have to wait for the mod. In the meanwhile it's good to have the request here for reference gathering opinions and contributions.

Comment: I mean, I guess it would be possible to do that with users (who have full editing privileges) and userscripts in a semi-automated way.

Comment: The heavy lifting here would also include compiling or a more or less exhaustive list of all IDE tags. Not only do you have the top 10 or so that anyone could probably think of, but you have about 10 specific-version tags for each of those, probably. Then there's the long tail of less popular or more specific IDEs that people may not know about.

Comment: It wouldn't be a major negative during this cleanup to *miss* less popular ide specific tags, given it wouldn't touch those cases.

Comment: @TylerH I compiled the list of IDEs about one year ago (I lost the file but I'll do it again and post the list as an answer). The problem was that there were well over 50 altogether, so using search it doesn't let you filter for so many tags in a single query. I'll compile the list and with some luck someone will throw them into a SEDE query.

Comment: @starball About the question you asked in the edit, those are mainly 2 cases. 1º *"feature parity"* questions like: *"I have functionality in IDE X how do I get the same in IDE Y?"* (a mod said in these cases only tag Y should be used and text search for the name of X on tag Y). 2º Questions about IDEs that share a significant amount of features (like IntelliJ IDEA, PyCharm, the JetBrains family) can sometimes be tagged for more than 1 IDE because the feature is identical. In either case the `ide` tag is still redundant.

Comment: @bad_coder note: for jetbrains IDEs, there is a dedicated tag, [tag:jetbrains-ide] (I wager most people asking questions about specific jetbrains IDEs in general don't know that that tag exists, or have the intuition to think to look for it or even wonder if they can/should generalize their question).

Comment: @starball I know about the `jetbrains-ide` tag, I think it's been getting less and less use because features have increasingly diverged between the IDEs over time. Even a slight feature change in UI, in naming, in whatever warrants a specific tag. But that's also an orthogonal problem (altough it's worth mentioning) in the scope of this thread.

Answer (score 8):

Going by your own admission:

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?** and **is it unambiguous?**

   Yes it's an IDE;
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   Yes programming tools are on-topic;
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

   I don't see [ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ide) adding anything meaningful to a question that's already been tagged as [eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse) or [visual-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio) for example.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   Yes.

Scoring only 1 out of 4, the [ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ide) tag shouldn't be burninated.

Comment: Mind you those aren't complete sentences but segments. Quoting them like that removes the argument being made. It could've been written as *"no, because"* but it wouldn't work as well, the arguments would've take a *nay-saying* form but I'm not an antagonistic kind of guy.

Comment: I enjoyed my literary freedom subverting 3 postitive definitions by saying *yes* to them (a sort of inverted double negation) to insert a non-obvious joke. I'm satisfied with how it came out.

Comment: I would say that this burnination proposal could probably be uncontroversially at least changed to a [meta-tag:cleanup] request to remove the usages where it's redundant (where another specific IDE tag is already also being used)

Comment: @starball why at all? Why specifically that case? If anything, the tag should be removed from a question when the question **is not** about an IDE as scoped in the tag excerpt. It does no harm if a question has both vscode and ide. Nobody gets confused about that.

Comment: @starball I'm all for clean-up, but that would require a new question. This answer is for the question as asked, burnination of the [tag:ide] tag.

Comment: @rene re "why" because it's not necessary, and it's really being used in that case as a [meta tag, which should be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging). if someone is really an expert in multiple specific IDEs and wants to see such questions, they should create a tag filter for those specific IDEs.

Comment: I wholeheartedly disagree @starball but here we are.

Comment: I thought I was (at least at a high level) agreeing with your answer to burnination question #3.

Comment: The score is 5 out of 4, because it's also a meta tag. But, 160 tags vs 3 edge case tags gives 1:30 meaning a *signal-to-noise* ratio of 3,3%... The tag isn't transmitting any signal anymore, it's over 96,6% noise.

Comment: I feel like none of the burnination criteria is _completely_ satisfied as I explained in some other answers like [this one from Dalija Prasnikar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/427777/10871900) and [my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/427763/10871900).

Comment: @dan1stiscrying I had seen your edit and was thinking on how to address the examples you included. One of them is perhaps the hardest example brought up until now, so I'm looking forward to sharing my thoughts on it. I'll try to write an answer later today or tomorrow.

Answer (score 7):

> 3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?
>
> I don't see ide adding anything meaningful to a question that's
> already been tagged as eclipse or visual-studio for example.

I don't think that this burnination point is fully satisfied.

While the tag does not add anything meaningful for the questions tagged as eclipse or visual-studio, it does add something meaningful for questions tagged with [delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi) Delphi is name used both for language and the IDE, and when you are asking questions related to the IDE part, such questions are commonly tagged with [ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ide), too.

Specifically, there are currently 390 questions marked with both tags. While this does not look like a large number, there are currently less than 52.000 Delphi questions asked, so that represents a significant number in that context.

Removing the [ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ide) tag would make those questions much harder to find and filter.

Optionally, there is a [delphi-ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi-ide) that could be used instead of plain [ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ide) in Delphi related questions. The disadvantage of using this longer tag is that it makes the whole tag section longer and repetitive.

Comment: Good post! I had noticed the Delphi tag but didn't know what IDE the language used. Apparently there's a [Delphi CE](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/starter) that's specifically an IDE *"(CE) is a full featured IDE"*? Since Delphi has a long history have its IDEs always been homonymous? Qs tagged CodeGear wouldn't be orphaned. Do you see a possible retag as making any sense? Are we missing any IDE? It seems a pattern is emerging that if there's a 1:1 correspondence between IDE and language (a minority case) then a separate tag tends to not have been created.

Comment: @bad_coder No, Delphi CE just means it is a free Community Edition. See [Delphi Product Editions](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/product-editions) Delphi has always been used as a name of the language and the IDE, despite the fact that there were some short time periods where company tried to push using Object Pascal as the language name, but it was never universally accepted by their customer base and eventually, they have given up on that.

Comment: There is additional name for the IDE which is RAD Studio, but that one is used by people that use both C++ and Delphi languages. If we start tagging Delphi IDE related questions with [tag:rad-studio] there will be plenty of confused people.

Comment: From Embarcadero there are several IDEs: [c++builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/[c++builder]) with 3,473 Qs and [interbase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interbase) with 367 Qs. Then you already mentioned [rad-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rad-studio) with 240 Qs. In the free products there are [dev-c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/[dev-c++]) -the tag seems to have a complex history, see the tag wiki. Also [pyscripter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyscripter) with 190 Qs. Only the Delphi IDE doesn't have an own tag

Comment: I understand the annoyance of loosing a transversal tag, but to have a comparison [try entering python into the tag search](https://stackoverflow.com/tags). Here you can see an example that Python was somewhat forced to specialize their tags by prefix e.g. [`python-typing`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-typing) or [`python-unittest`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-unittest) or [`python-import`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-import) to name a few... In practice it's always better to have a single tag that allows one-click filtering.

Comment: I kind of saw this coming from you and was thinking of raising it myself, but really I have the same comment as I had for the answer post about google apps script. **If your specific technology has its own editor tool, then instead of relying on a meta tag to filter for such questions, you should use the dedicated tag for it.** It being longer in character length is just something you should accept.

Comment: Didn't they always insist on calling the language Object Pascal, to keep it different from the IDE Delphi?

Comment: @Lundin Only briefly. Developers never really accepted it.

Answer (score 1):

In past burninations of large tags the mods could ask staff to remove the tag from some posts provided questions wouldn't be left without any tags. In this case,  from questions that have a second IDE specific tag the [ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ide) can safely be removed.

#### Sizing up the problem

- I've compiled a list of IDE tags having **at least 3 questions** also tagged [ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ide) there's 162 in total (see the list below). Some text editors included.
- This leaves out about 1500 tags that have 1 single post also using [ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ide).
- There are around 800 tags that have 2 questions also tagged [ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ide).

Using [starball's SEDE query](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/427762) with the IDE tag list below, we get total of:

7189 questions

if we also include the Delphi IDE (so far one of only three outlying IDEs without a dedicated tag that've been brought up) mentioned in [Dalija Prasnikar's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/427777) under a hypothetical retag, that brings the total to:

7550 questions

Subtracting from a total of 10,943 tagged [ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ide), that would leave:

3,393 questions, or 31% of the total.

Generally during a burnination 20%-25% need to be closed, if we consider many of the tags having only 1 or 2 questions tagged [ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ide) will need a retag because they're missing their specific IDE tag, it leaves us within the usual average for burninations.

#### Honorable mentions and edge cases:

1. The [Code Bubbles IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Code+Bubbles%22) could use its own tag.
2. Prime examples of questions that are only tagged [ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ide), even if a language tag had been added it would still not be enough:

   [No mapping... error when clicking on a unit tab on the IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77769441)

   [interlliJ IDE - idea. command line code is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77651949)

```py
IDEs = (
    "eclipse",
    "intellij-idea",
    "visual-studio",
    "netbeans",
    "phpstorm",
    "editor",
    "android-studio",
    "visual-studio-code",
    "pycharm",
    "webstorm",
    "jetbrains-ide",
    "xcode",
    "visual-studio-2010",
    "vim",
    "emacs",
    "spyder",
    "visual-studio-2008",
    "eclipse-plugin",
    "text-editor",
    "clion",
    "codeblocks",
    "visual-studio-2012",
    "development-enviorment",
    "visual-studio-2013",
    "atom-editor",
    "qt-creator",
    "visual-studio-2015",
    "sublimetext2",
    "sublimetext3",
    "visual-studio-2017",
    "visual-studio-2019",
    "eclipse-cdt",
    "sublimetext",
    "rstudio",
    "notepad++",
    "rider",
    "c++builder",
    "netbeans-7",
    "resharper",
    "visual-studio-2022",
    "dreamweaver",
    "visual-studio-2005",
    "cloud9-ide",
    "code-editor",
    "monodevelop",
    "jdeveloper",
    "intellij-14",
    "netbeans-8",
    "dev-c++",
    "eclipse-pdt",
    "zend-studio",
    "codelite",
    "spring-tool-suite",
    "selenium-ide",
    "komodo",
    "xcode4",
    "myeclipse",
    "neovim",
    "eclipse-juno",
    "kdevelop",
    "vscode-extensions",
    "vi",
    "monaco-editor",
    "javafx",
    "ssms",
    "appcode",
    "adobe-brackets",
    "emmet",
    "designer",
    "eric-ide",
    "lazarus",
    "datagrip",
    "eclipse-luna",
    "android-studio-3.0",
    "flexbuilder",
    "coda",
    "eclipse-indigo",
    "android-gradle-plugin",
    "intellij-13",
    "eclipse-neon",
    "xcode5",
    "sharpdevelop",
    "oracle-sqldeveloper",
    "bluej",
    "netbeans6.8",
    "jenkins",
    "netbeans6.7",
    "gedit",
    "rad-studio",
    "lighttable",
    "visual-studio-express",
    "ibm-rad",
    "mercurial",
    "visual-studio-mac",
    "netbeans-6.9",
    "phped",
    "xcode6",
    "eclipse-rcp",
    "eclipse-3.5",
    "xamarin-studio",
    "ptvs",
    "eclipse-jdt",
    "arduino-ide",
    "radrails",
    "nitrousio",
    "cloud9",
    "jetbrains-rider",
    "uniface",
    "ssis",
    "jgrasp",
    "scala-ide",
    "pyscripter",
    "android-ide",
    "flash-cs5",
    "eclipse-che",
    "keil",
    "rodeo",
    "ace-editor",
    "visual-web-developer",
    "liteide",
    "zerobrane",
    "codenvy",
    "android-studio-2.3",
    "leksah",
    "phpstorm-2017.2",
    "jedit",
    "wing-ide",
    "php-ide",
    "xcode7",
    "scintilla",
    "codeanywhere",
    "html-editor",
    "visual-editor",
    "xcode8",
    "terminal-ide",
    "komodoedit",
    "eclipse-wtp",
    "wireshark",
    "eclipse-wtp",
    "egit",
    "liferay-ide",
    "webmatrix",
    "intellij-idea-2016",
    "anypoint-studio",
    "c++builder-6",
    "mysql-workbench",
    "jcreator",
    "force.com",
    "phpstorm-2016.1",
    "jenkins-pipeline",
    "eclipse-marketplace",
    "scite",
    "visual-studio-2003",
    "appcelerator",
    "windowbuilder",
    "visual-assist",
    "nodeclipse",
    "juce",
    "wxwidgets",
    "powerbuilder",
    "c++builder-xe5",
    "phpmyadmin",
)
```

Answer (score -6):

As a SME in [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script), we use [ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ide) to tag questions specifically related to the inbuilt ide. This serves to categorise ide related questions from scripting questions. Excel's vba  also has a [inbuilt ide](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420699/are-questions-specific-to-excel-vbas-ide-considered-on-topic/420701#comment929119_420702) and would benefit from this tag. We usually don't have a specific name for this ide.

I would prefer avoiding complete burnination of the tag, for usage in questions, where a more specific ide tag is unavailable or not applicable(see dan1st-is-crying's answer https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/427763).  With that in mind, I also agree with [starball's proposal of automating tag removals where unnecessary](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/427762):

> just automate removal of the tag on any question that also has a tag for a specific IDE / editor

If that's not feasible, A tag warning would also be worth considering:

> If you already tagged a specific IDE tag(vscode, vim..), [ide] is not needed.

Comment: When you say *"we use `ide` to tag"* you've notice that [`ide`+`google-apps-script`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script+ide) **only has 61 Qs**  and [`ide`+`excel`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel+ide) a **whopping 17 Qs :O**? I'm a huge fan of *"transversal tags"* the hallmark example being datatypes like [`enums`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/enums) but in this specific case the community/tag system as a whole started moving towards specialization long ago, the trend being so established it should now be consolidated.

Comment: I like this post a lot! Because it gives two good counter-examples that combined (78 Qs) are still **two orders of magnitude less** than the 7k examples starball's query caught where the `ide` tag is only adding noise to the tag system.

Comment: I kind of see the utility here, but the guidance on not doing meta tags leads me to suggest that you just retag these with a specific tag for the google apps script IDE.

Comment: @starball `google-apps-script-editor` is a exceptionally long tag and we once had it... it was a pain to add this and a pain to see it in questions with a bunch of `google-apps-script-`... we hated it so much that the tag is now synonymized to the parent. [History](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400145/merge-google-apps-script-editor-to-google-apps-script)

Comment: @bad_coder Should quantity matter in this case?  I propose that this tag be used as a exception tag - if used in that manner, it is to be expected that the quantity would be less. It is used  to categorize within a parent tag and for that purpose, I find it a useful tag. I'm also not opposed against **just automate removal of the tag on any question that also has a tag for a specific IDE / editor** (- starball). I just want to prevent complete burnination of the tag.

Comment: @TheMaster quantity matters because of scale! It takes me little over a week to curate 78 Qs and seeing newbie users constantly adding the redundant `ide` tag is a continued source of work that will only go away when the tag is burninated. Taken over that list of 100 IDEs (still to be completed) in the other answer that's a lot of curation effort that can only be solved by burnination, because as long as there's an `ide` tag new users will spam it every chance they get.

Comment: @TheMaster the process isn't as automated as you think. A mod has to carefully review the case, then send a list of actions to staff, that gets run **once** and then the community is left to their own devices. Meaning that selective automated removal every time the tag gets added to a post isn't an option.

Comment: @bad_coder I don't think "redundancy" is barely a reason for undertaking such a huge burnination. In fact you answered almost all burnination questions as Yes and it doesn't cause any harm. I think this is worth reconsidering. *"Yeah, but your scientists were so preoccupied with whether they could, they didn't stop to think if they should"* I believe you(not you specifically) have the manpower to plow through now and that's the only reason that there's a trend for burninating tags that cause a minor inconvenience. If burnination was hard as it was, a few years back, we wouldn't be discussing.

Comment: @TheMaster I didn't want to make this argument, but: at present [`ide` fulfills the definition of meta-tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/meta-tags/info) because it has become redundant. The 4 burnination criteria are satisfied. I wouldn't say burninations have become easy, as I've [given a fair contribution](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/users) and it felt like a lot of work.

Comment: @TheMaster it has yet to be determined how much work this burnination would be. The list of IDEs has to be completed and then further research is needed on the nature of the remaining Qs.

Comment: @bad_coder No, [IDE doesn't fulfill the definition of meta-tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/400104/).  How did it satisy the 4 criteria, when all answers are "Yes, but"? I do appreciate your honesty in answering "Yes" though, unlike other burnination requests, which are basically lies. Even if you answered "no", I'm fairly certain burnination will go through, because of available manpower. And burninations such as these, if it's hard now, would've been impossible  and not even considered - just a few years back. It's a fact that this is only happening because of available manpower.

Comment: @TheMaster you need to read the full sentences instead of reducing them to a single word.